# Symfony Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted WebProfilerBundle Twig render as service

Tags: php, symfony, out-of-memory, twig, render

Since I migrated my Symfony 2.1 I'm having a problem with the WebProfilerBundle. The profiler bar is shown, but when I click on a link it will show a blank page. In the PHP error file the following error is shown.

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4194304 bytes) in C:\Work\Projects\DirectpayLogin\solution\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent.php on line 102

The error location is random. So not always StopwatchEvent.php.

I've narrowed down the problem to this file:
\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\Resources\views\Profiler\layout.html.twig

In this template the twig render service functions are causing the problem. If I replace the render service with render controller is does work.

So I'm replacing this line:
{{ render(path('_wdt', { 'token': token, 'position': 'normal' })) }}
With this line:
{% render controller('web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction',{ 'token': token, 'position': 'normal' }) %}

So it seems my Symfony has a problem with rendering controllers as a service.
But why? The problem started from version 2.2 and I'm now running 2.7.

Setting my php.ini memory_limit to -1 will still give this error. It will only take longer. It seems to be a loop of some kind.

PHP version is 5.6 and my dev pc runs windows 7 and iis 7

I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Same error after setting the limit to -1 - does that mean you get the same limit even if you change it? Did you restart your php process (webserver or php-fpm)? Did you edit the correct php.ini?

Comment: With -1 I should get unlimited memory and so it takes longer till I get the same error but at some point Symfony still runs out of memory. Yes I restarted php and the setting is picked up, but Symfony seems to be in some kind of loop and at some point still runs out of memory.